# ZendFramework - How to load CSV file into database, on duplicate insert next record without auto exit?

Tags: php, mysql, zend-framework, zend-db

I have 500 rows in CSV. 400 Is inserted and 401 is duplicate, it does not allow me to insert after 401 the rest. I need to manually find the CSV file and edit it.

But how can i tell Zend_Db adapter, on duplicate continue next one, if next one is also duplicate continue to next one, but do not exit unless all rows are scaned.

Example:

```
  $row = Application_Model_Csv::processFile("/var/tmp/csv.csv");
  foreach($row as $k=>$v)
  {
    $insert =array(
      'groups' => $v[0],
      'country'=> $v[1],
      'name' =>$v[2],    /* Unique key */
      'url' => $v[3]
    );
    $this->db->insert("something", $insert);
  }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use REPLACE instead of INSERT. Zend Framework doesn't have specific method for this, but you can make a custom query:

```
$this->db->getAdapter()->query('REPLACE INTO `something` (`groups`, `country`, `name`, `url`)
VALUES ("' . $v[0] . '", "' . $v[1] . '", "' . $v[2] . '", "' . $v[3] . '")');
```